# How to get category detail along with subcategories and products in PHP file not PHTML?

Tags: magento2.2, category-tree

I have looked over internet but can't find a solution to get detail in my controller or block file i have tried

- Registry
- Tried get id of category from param
- Also tried from ***Magento\Catalog\Model\Category*** by injecting it.

Comment: you mean get it using controller?

Comment: yes get in my controller i am not using phtml file i am redirecting it to another ui form where i need that detail.

Comment: do you want to get specific category with category ID?

Comment: yes specific category that I selected like "women" i want complete detail of that category